# Wordpress Website not indexing in google, no error on google webmaster

Tags: seo, google, web-crawlers, robots.txt, google-index

I just recognized my SEO Score is 0 and that my wordpress website is not indexed on google search engine, no automatic filling as well. I am not an expert, I never used a sitemap, nor htaccess but it still worked always! After checking through analysis I found out that there is no title tag, no description, no meta keywords and headings, text html ratio is 0% , lots of syntax errors....idk what happened as I didnt change the website's structure, I just added something as its normal to keep the page updated...
Google webmaster shows I have to index my page! I dont understand why, I never used blackhat SEO or anything fraud

my robots txt shows this 
User-agent: * 
Disallow: /wp-admin/ 
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

I know there are plenty of problems, but can someone tell me how i can easily make the page visible again as I dont know much about this? it always worked...maybe show me how a sitemap should look like and to prevent search bots to index wp admin, and if htaccess is important and how It should look like..is robots txt ok ?
Thank you very much,  I am getting frustrated as I think I lost everything even if this problem is fresh (max 2 months)

Comment: Step 1:  If you have a robots.txt file in your root directory, it might be telling Google not to index your site.  Have you checked for that?  Usually it is safe to just delete (or rename) those files since it sounds like you DO want to be indexed.  This can be a deal-breaker if you are trying to get Google Adsense to work on your WP site.  No matter where you put your special code, if you are not being indexed you will be told your site is down so they could not verify it.